# Get an element's style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on something where I would need to return an element's style and print it in the HTML page itself. Okay I know how to print it but the problem is how do I get the element. To test if it would print the style I tried

```
console.log(document.getElementById('something').style.fontSize);
```

but it returns undefined, even though 'something' does have a set font size.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Needing/wanting to "read" the style from an element is often a sign of somehow trying to maintain application state in the style information, and there are usually better ways to approach things.

Answer (score 7):

You need to get the computed style.

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('something'), null);
```

So replace your code with:

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('something'), null)
  .getPropertyValue("fontSize"));
```

<sub>See `Window.getComputedStyle()`</sub>

Comment: It says `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Comment: @SirMaxime You are giving a wrong ID there then...

Comment: @SirMaxime Do not unaccept answers like this after you accept. But please let us knwo what's the problem. This is not ethical.

Comment: No, I verified multiple times it is the correct ID.

Comment: Show your full code in fiddle...